# TimestampType set override error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to create my own Hibernate mapping to read and write UTC Timestamps to DB with Hibernate, so I am extending the Hibernate TimestampType class as shown below, but I always get the following error. So can someone please help by telling me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks for your time.

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - The method set(PreparedStatement, Object, int) of type UTCTimestampType must override or implement a supertype method
>   - Name clash: The method set(PreparedStatement, Object, int) of type UTCTimestampType has the same erasure as set(PreparedStatement, T,
>   int) of type AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType but does not
>   override it

```
public class UTCTimestampType extends org.hibernate.type.TimestampType{

        @Override
        public Object get(ResultSet rs, String name) throws SQLException {
            return rs.getTimestamp(name, createUTCCalendar());
        }

        private static Calendar createUTCCalendar() {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeZone(new SimpleTimeZone(0, "UTC"));
            return c;
        }

        @Override
        public void set(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index)
                    throws SQLException{
            Timestamp ts;
            if (value instanceof Timestamp) {
                ts = (Timestamp) value;
            } else {
                ts = new Timestamp(((java.util.Date)value).getTime());
            }
            st.setTimestamp(index, ts, createUTCCalendar());
        }   
}
```

Comment: did you extend `UTCTimestampType` in some class?

Comment: @JigarJoshi no as I can't even compile UTCTimestampType in the first place

Comment: can you post hibernate version and jdk version on your questino

Comment: @JigarJoshi I am using hibernate-core-3.6.0.Final.jar in my app and JDK 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Java Doc for TimestampType:

[TimestampType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/TimestampType.html)
it extends

```
AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date>
```

The method signature is `set(PreparedStatement st, T value, int index)` not with Object

Try:

```
@Override
        public void set(PreparedStatement st, Date value, int index)
                    throws SQLException{...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well this explains the error, as I was using Hibernate 3.6 jar while this code is more for Hibernate 3.5...one last question please...won't changing Object to Date cause me trouble for the custom mapping to read and write UTC Timestamps to DB with Hibernate as mentioned in my question?

Comment: Can't answer the second question. You have to try it. Since TimestampType extends AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType<Date> the type(T) is Date, so I don't think it will cause problems.

Comment: You can try to override it with T: public void set(PreparedStatement st, T value, int index). Not sure if it will work.

Comment: This doesn't work with the latest Hibernate 5.2.9Final. "The method get(PreparedStatement, Date, int) of type UTCTimestampType must override or implement a super type method".